# wxPython how to find parent/container of a selected node in a DataViewTreeCtrl?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I use [DataViewTreeCtrl](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.dataview.DataViewTreeCtrl.html) to show a parents-children [tree](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.dataview.DataViewItem.html#wx.dataview.DataViewItem) and I want to remove a parent (Container) once the last child of it is removed. I could not find a method to get the container/parent of a child from `GetSelections()` and the only way I can seem to think of is writing an algorithm that will iterate through the entire tree to find the selected item and its parent that will be called each time an item is to be removed.

Comment: You've posted no code but given that you are displaying the children of a parent, you must know the parent already. The parent has a `GetChildCount` function i.e. once at zero, you can delete it. If this doesn't fit your usage, you'll have to post your code and a clear explanation of the issue.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I use `GetSelections` to get the currently selected items so I do not see any way from here to get to their parents without manually iterating from the root node.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example